# Is there anyway to intercept chrome's notification?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to know if there is any way I can make an extension for chrome so I can intercept the notifications, so I can make something with that (like start a program, etc). In chrome for desktop.

Comment: The desktop one, there is the PushBullet notification, AutoRemote notification, google+ notification, etc...

Comment: You cannot modify the behavior of other extensions, but for web pages you could monkeypatch the `Notification` constructor such that the created notification launches a profram on the desktop. To launch a native program you will need to put create non-extension component that launches the external program and use [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) to communicate with it. Don't neglect security though.

Comment: I dont want to modify the behavior of the extensions, just intercept, like a watcher, one the notification appears my extension do something.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: If I try to catch the proccess? like when the notification appears it launch a new proccess, right?

Comment: No, there is no new process for a notification. Your easiest alternative is to fork the source code of the extension, modify the notification code and load it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54461/discussion-between-caio-keto-and-rob-w).